# General persist method in Entity Framework - inserting or updating (if exists) entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository

What is the best solution in entity framework to implement generic persist method?

For example there is a Company entity:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Id property can be generated before entity is stored into the Database.

So the task is to implement Persist method:

```
public class Repository
{
    private DbSet<Company> _dbSet;

    public void Persist(Company company)
    {
        // How to implement body here to Add entity if it doesn't exists yet
        // or Modify it in opposit case?
        // In terms of database entity record is required to be inserted or updated.
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example where you can't recognize if a `Company` instance is new or has been formerly loaded from the database you must query the DB:

```
public void Persist(Company company)
{
    var companyInDb = _dbSet.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == company.Id);
    if (companyInDb != null)
    {
        _context.Entry(companyInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(company);
    }
    else
    {
        _dbSet.Add(company);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, you need a reference to the context `_context` in your repository.

An alternative approach is possible if you mark the company as new or loaded from the DB, for example with a special constructor:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
    }

    public Company(bool isNew)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _isNew = isNew;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isNew;
    public IsNew { get { return _isNew; } }
}
```

The `Persist` method wouldn't then need to load the original:

```
public void Persist(Company company)
{
    if (!company.IsNew)
    {
        _context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        _dbSet.Add(company);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that all this only updates scalar properties of the company, not relationships.

Comment: @Slauma: For your second option, what if the objects don't come from the database, but from another source to be synchronized with the database, and so you again don't know if the object is new?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: Then the second option can't be used, only the first option. If you want to avoid to query the DB I think your only option is to write a Stored Procedure that decides if the object needs to be inserted or updated. I would certainly start with option 1 and think about a Stored Proc only if I encounter serious performance problems.

Comment: @Slauma: Perhaps the query for the id would perform very well. I'll have to try it.  Thanks.